# RDC to Windows 2000 Server from OS X 10.6.8 immediately crashes

Tags: mac-osx, remote-desktop, rdp, windows-2000

I'm using Remote Desktop Connection 2.11 on Mac OS X 10.6.8, trying to connect to a Windows 2000 Server. I type in the IP (local) and it warns me that it can't verify the identity of the computer, I hit "Connect", it opens a black window (as if it were about to work) then immediately crashes:

```
Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 2.0

Error Signature:
Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
Date/Time: 2012-02-28 09:22:46 -0800
Application Name: Remote Desktop Connection
Application Bundle ID: com.microsoft.rdc
Application Signature: MSRD
Application Version: 2.1.1.110309
Crashed Module Name: TSClient
Crashed Module Version: 1.0
Crashed Module Offset: 0x000b927f
Blame Module Name: TSClient
Blame Module Version: 1.0
Blame Module Offset: 0x000b927f
Application LCID: 1033
Extra app info: Reg=en Loc=0x0409 
Crashed thread: 6
```

Anyone have any ideas on what I can do to get it to work? It works perfectly fine connecting to Win Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Can you connect to the Win2K box from another PC?

Comment: Not sure, don't have access to another PC. I downloaded an open-source program on the Mac called CoRD which let me connect to the Win2k box, but I'd rather not use that program if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I'm not surprised. Support for Windows 2000 Server ended on July 13, 2010. So it's probably a client-software fault because it can't handle the exception thrown by Win2K.